# Unable to print session variables in twig in symfony3

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm trying to access the session variables in the twig which is set in the controller. For some reasons it's not working in twig. I have checked the session variables printing in another controller which is giving the expected result but the variable shows empty in template. I don't know whether I'm missing something in configuration.

```
//Below is my code in controller

$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('user', [
    'id' => $user->getId(), 
    'firstName' => $user->getfirstname()
]);

// code in twig
{{ dump(app.session) }}
```

Comment: Are you handing the `$session` variable over to twig?

Comment: No. I'm not passing $session variable over to twig. I'm thinking its global configuration hence explicitly not passing the $session array over to twig. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, stupid me! You are of course right regarding the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't presume that session variables are global.

I've done this and you need to pass via array when rendering your Twig. Something like this:

```
return $this->render('my_twig_file.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $session->get('user'),
));
```

Then in Twig dump it:

```
{{ dump(user) }}
```

Also, make sure you don't use dump in your PROD environment. You might want to comment the dump out when you are done testing, or use a different file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on myself. I have used the custom twig extension to access the global variables like session without any issues. Just find the code below.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html